# Extract URL Query String ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

What is the correct way to extract a query string in ES6?

I have written this function:

```
getUrlParams(queryString) {
    const hashes = queryString.slice(queryString.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    const params = {};
    hashes.map((hash) => {
      const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
      params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
    });

    return params;
  }
```

However ESLint compains that it expected this to be used by class method and it expected a return value in the arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.map` when you don't care about the return value; use `.forEach` instead:

```
hashes.forEach(hash => {
  const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
});
```

See, `.map` function is usually expected to return a new collection (where each item represents some relation to the item of the original collection).

In fact, you can simplify this with `.reduce()`:

```
const params = hashes.reduce((params, hash) => {
  const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
  return params;
}, {});
return params;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I am still getting an error stating that `getUrlParams(queryString)` expected this. I am calling this method inside my `getSearchResults() ` as `const { terms, category } = this.getUrlParams(this.props.location.search);`

Comment: You're welcome. As for new error, I'd rather make a new question for this - it seems to be more about the structure of your component then about algorithms used.

Answer (score 0):

It complains because `map` is supposed to map function argument to its return value, not just iterate.

It can be changed to simple loop:

```
const params = {};
for (const hash of hashes) {
  const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
}
```

Or an array can be reduced to an object:

```
return hashes.reduce((params, hash) => {
  const [key, val] = hash.split('=');
  params[key] = decodeURIComponent(val);
}, {});
```